# vertical and horizontal centering leads to hidden elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Below code snippet has 6 `form-group`. And everything is styled using Bootstrap 4 to have vertically and horizontally centered. Center alignment actually works but when I resize the browser window vertically some elements at the top were hidden from browser's **scrollbar**(please run the code snippet to see that).

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body,
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 col-sm-11">
                <form class="form-control" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 1
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 2
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 3
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 4
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 5
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 6
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use 100vh to set `min-height` on the row.

https://www.codeply.com/go/fURhmFAJiC

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .min-100 {
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row min-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 col-sm-11">
                <form class="form-control" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 1
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 2
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 3
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 4
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 5
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm pt-0 pb-0">
                            Email 6
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `min-height` to `.h-100` to achieve it

```
.h-100 {
    height: 100%!important;
    min-height: 393px; // Added
}
```

If you are unable to add css to `h-100`, you can add your own class with `h-100` in HTML and give `min-height` to that class. for example

```
<div class="h-100 myForm">

</div>
```

and your css will be like this

```
.myForm {
  min-height: 393px;
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8uovbmb3/1/)

Comment: It works the same as my example in the question. When I resize it still has the issue. But anyway @ZimSystem provided answer.